# Filter an Array using another Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
   val value = Array["id","sd","cd"]  -- List of columns 
   val cols_list = Array["cd","id","tm","no","in","ts","nm"] -  -- List of columns
```

i want a list with columns not in cols_list.

code i tried as below :

```
     val newcol = for (x <- cols_list if x.toString.toUpperCase() not in value )
```

it's throwing error as value not is not a member of String.
is there a way that we can achieve?
Please suggest.

Comment: `val finallist = cols_list.filterNot(value.contains(_))`  you can use

Comment: "not in " ... Scala is not Python. I'm also wondering why you added tags for "Apache Spark"? What is the relation to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplest is `filterNot` method (Apart from `diff`) that returns all elements from a list for which your function returns false.

```
val value = Array("id","sd","cd")  // List of columns
     val cols_list = Array("cd","id","tm","no","in","ts","nm")

     val finallist = cols_list.filterNot(value.contains(_)) //cols_list.par.filterNot also you can use
     println(finallist.mkString(" "))
 }
```

Result : `tm no in ts nm`

---

How it works...

filter creates a collection with those elements that do not satisfy the predicate p and discarding the rest. **This is collection level and will work for all Collections API in scala** 
signature :

```
  def filterNot(p: (A) => Boolean): Collection[A]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ram Ghadiyaram. Thanks for your help. I need  to convert value,col_list to upper case and then get the final list. Also i don't want to use map operations. Since map operation will take longer time and write everything to a single partition.

Answer (score 0):

use `.diff` to get list of columns not in cols_list

```
val value = Array("id","sd","cd")
val cols_list = Array("cd","id","tm","no","in","ts","nm")
value.diff(cols_list)
//Array[String] = Array(sd)

//case insensitive 
value.map(x => x.toUpperCase).diff(cols_list.map(x => x.toUpperCase)).map(x => x.toLowerCase)
//Array[String] = Array(sd)
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
cols_list.diff(value)
//Array[String] = Array(tm, no, in, ts, nm)

cols_list.map(x => x.toUpperCase).diff(value.map(x => x.toUpperCase)).map(x => x.toLowerCase)
//Array[String] = Array(tm, no, in, ts, nm)

cols_list.map(x => x.toUpperCase).diff(value.map(x => x.toUpperCase)).map(x => "\"a." + x.toLowerCase + "\"").mkString(",")
//String = "a.tm","a.no","a.in","a.ts","a.nm"
```

Comment: Thank you Shu for your prompt response. I tried but  i am not seeing the expected output. I am expecting the values not in value should be displayed as below.     "tm","no","in","ts","nm"

Comment: Change this - value.diff(cols_list) to cols_list.diff(value) you will get above values.

Comment: @sparkscala, Please check the `updated` answer, we just need to `inter change` **cols_list and value**..!

Comment: Actually i missed one thing. I want to add something like below for the output.                             "a.tm","a.no","a.in","a.ts","a.nm" .Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @sparkscala, use `cols_list.map(x => x.toUpperCase).diff(value.map(x => x.toUpperCase)).map(x => "\"a." + x.toLowerCase + "\"").mkString(",")` if the answer helped Click on **`Upvote and Accept`**!